# Sufficient condition for a probability distribution on $\mathbb Z_p$ to admit a square-root w.r.t convolution

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, pr.probability, polynomials, fourier-analysis, convolution

Let $p \ge 2$ be a positive integer, and let $Q \in \mathcal P(\mathbb Z_p)$ be a probability distribution on $\mathbb Z_p$.

> **Question.** What are necessary and sufficient conditions on $Q$ to ensure that the later admits a square-root w.r.t convolution, i.e such that there exists $D \in \mathcal P(\mathbb Z_p)$ verifying $D \star D = Q$ ?

I'm particularly, interested in the case where $Q$ is Zipf, i.e $Q(k) \propto (k+1)^{-\beta}$ for some $\beta \gt 1$.

### An illustrative example

Consider the case where $p = 2$. Let $a := Q(0)$, $b:=Q(1)$, $x:=D(0)$, and $y := D(1)$. We are interested in the feasibility of the following system.
\begin{align}
a &= x^2 + y^2,\\
b &= xy + yx = 2xy,\\
1 &= x + y,\\
x &\ge 0,\\
y &\ge 0.
\end{align}
Substituting $y = x - 1$ gives $2x(1-x) = b$, i.e $2x^2 - 2x + b = 0$, which evaluates to
\begin{eqnarray}
x_\pm = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 8b}}{4} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 2b}}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}
For this to be real, we require
$$
b \le 1/2.
$$
With this condition, note that $x_+ + x_- = 1$ and $x_+, x_- \ge 0$. Take $x=x_+$ and $y=x_-$.  Now, the first equation (the circle) reduces to the requirement

$$
a = x_+^2 + x_-^2 = 2\left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1-2b}{4}\right) = 1-b,
$$
i.e $a+b=1$, which is satisfied since $Q$ is a distribution. We conclude that in the case $p=2$, the answer to our question is affirmative if $b \le 1/2$. It's easy to check that this condition is also necessary (i.e $D$ doesn't exist when $b \gt 1/2$).

### Edit: Exploring an idea based on Fourier analysis

This is based on some comments by user Paul Garrett.

---

So, $\mathbb Z_p$ is a compact (in fact finite!) group, and so we must have Fourier transform $\hat Q:\mathbb Z_p \to \mathbb C$, given by
$$
\hat Q(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt p}\sum_{x \in \mathbb Z_p} Q(x) e^{-2i\pi kx / p}.
$$
The convolution theorem then gives
$$
\hat D^2(k) = \hat Q(k),\text{ for all }k \in \mathbb Z_p.
$$

For $p=2$, one has
$$
\begin{split}
\hat Q(k) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sum_{x \in \mathbb Z_2} Q(x) e^{-i\pi kx} = \frac{Q(0) + Q(1) e^{-i\pi k}}{\sqrt 2} = \frac{a + be^{-i\pi k}}{\sqrt 2}.
\end{split}
$$
Thus, $\hat Q(0) = (Q(0) + Q(1))/\sqrt 2 = 1/\sqrt 2$ and
$$
\hat Q(1) = \frac{Q(0) + Q(1) e^{-i\pi}}{\sqrt 2} = \frac{Q(0) - Q(1)}{\sqrt 2} = \frac{1 - 2b}{\sqrt 2},
$$
since $Q(0) - Q(1) = a-b = 1-b-b = 1-2b$.
The convolution theorem above then translates to
$$
\hat D(0)^2 = 1,\quad \hat D(1)^2 = \frac{1-2b}{2}.
$$
This is only solvable if $b \le 1/2$ (aha !), in which case we must have
$$
\hat D(0) = \pm 1,\quad \hat D(1) = \pm \sqrt{1-2b}.
$$

Inverting this hopefully recovers the result we previously obtained.

Indeed,

$$
\begin{split}
D(0) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z_2} \hat D(k) e^{-i\pi k \cdot 0} = \frac{\hat D(0) + \hat D(1)}{\sqrt 2} = \frac{\pm 1 \pm \sqrt{1-2b}}{2},\\
D(1) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z_2} \hat D(k) e^{-i\pi k} = \frac{\hat D(0) - \hat D(1)}{2} = \frac{\pm 1 \mp \sqrt{1-2b}}{2}.
\end{split}
$$
We can then extract those that verify the condition $D(0) + D(1) = 1$, $D(0),D(1) \ge 0$, giving

$$
\begin{split}
D(0) &= \frac{1 + \sqrt{1-2b}}{2},\text{ and }D(1) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-2b}}{2}, \text{ OR },\\
&\text{The reverse, i.e in the above, swap }D(0),\,D(1).
\end{split}
$$
This precisely recovers what we obtained earlier above !

I'm not sure (but am hopeful) this method can be used to address the case of any $p \ge 3$.

Comment: Just to be clear, $\mathbb Z_p$ is the $p$-adic integers? In general, since this is a compact topological group, its dual is discrete, and on the Fourier expansion side, convolution becomes pointwise multiplication... ?!?

Comment: @paul garrett - Judging by the "illustrative example", $\mathbb Z_p$ is the order $p$ cyclic group. Anyway, formula $Q(k) \propto (k+1)^{-\beta}$ from the question is not compatible with either interpretation.

Comment: @RW, thanks, I'm glad it was not just me wondering...

Comment: @paulgarrett $\mathbb Z_p := \mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z$ is simply the integers modulo $p$. I guess your remark still holds about Fourier, that's $\widehat D^2 = \widehat Q$, right ?

Comment: @dohmatob, $\mathbb Z/p$ is "self-dual", so general ideas of harmonic/Fourier analysis still apply... and "Fourier transform/series/etc" still converts convolution to pointwise multiplication. The meaning of the $(1+k)^{\beta}$ is very unclear, though...

Comment: OK, I read you. I've made an small update in the question which does a calculation based on your insightful comment. Thanks again.

Comment: The $(1+k)^{-\beta}$ thing: What I mean is that $Q(0) = c$, $Q(1) = c2^{-\beta}$, $Q(p-1) = cp^{-\beta}$, with $c$ chosen so that $\sum_k Q(k) = 1$.

Comment: Fourier analysis indeed recovers the "manual" solution I obtained earlier using basic algebraic manipulation. On think that felt a bit unnatural was working with $D$ and $Q$ as if the where just any functions on $\mathbb Z_p$ (i.e not probability) distributions, and then plugging the probability constraints at the end. I was wondering if there is a standard nice way to do Fourier analysis of **probability functions on finite discrete structure like $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: Isn't it therefore as simple as $\widehat{Q}(k)\geq 0$?

Comment: Ah, i think that might be it ! Good catch. You mean $\mathrm{Re} (\hat Q(k)) \ge 0$, or is $\hat Q(k)$ always guaranteed to be real ?

Comment: I think the Fourier transform does *not* map $Z_p$ to $Z_p$ but $Z_p$ to the complex numbers.

Comment: That was a typo, fixed.

Comment: I don't understand your comment "this is only solvable if $\dots$". Do you mean over $\mathbb{R}$? Because for $p\geq 3$ one expects $\widehat{Q}(1), \widehat{Q}(2),\dots$ to be $\mathbb{C}$-valued in general, so reasoning via solvability over $\mathbb{R}$ seems like it may be specific to the case of $p = 2$ where $\widehat{Q}(0), \widehat{Q}(1)\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Mark You're right. I was a bit sloppy there, and feared this would come back to hunt me. My hope is that $b \gt 1/2$ would break something down the line even in the complex / rigorous argument. Will fix asap.

Comment: And this is indeed the case for $p=2$; can't get real $D(1)$ if $b \gt 1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

You are interested in the probability measures $\mu$ that have a square root. If, instead, one imposes a somewhat stronger condition and requires existence of roots of **all** degrees (i.e., for any $n>1$ there is a measure $\rho$ whose $n$-th convolution power $\rho^{*n}$ is $\mu$), then the measures with this property on a group $G$  are called **infinitely divisible**.

If $G$ is finite, then there is a pretty explicit description of inifnitely divisible measures. Roughly speaking, these are precisely the measures obtained by an appropriately defined "exponential map". More precisely, a probability measure $\mu$ on $G$ is infinitely divisible iff there exist a positive measure $\lambda$ on $G$ (not necessarily a probability one!) and a finite subgroup $H\subset G$ such that
$$
\mu = e^{-\|\lambda\|} \bigl( e^{m*\lambda*m} + m - \delta_e \bigr) \;,
$$
where $m=m_H$ is the uniform probability measure on $H$, and
$$
e^\theta = \delta_e + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n!} \theta^{*n} 
$$
is the usual exponent in the group algebra of $G$ (this is Theorem 3.2.9 in the book [Probability measures on locally compact groups](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=501241) by Heyer).

I have to add that condition $Q(k)=C(k+1)^{-\beta}$ seems to be rather unnatural in this context as, for instance $p-1=-1$ (mod $p$). Moreover, any element of $\mathbb Z_p$ is a generator if $p$ is simple.

Comment: Thanks (upvoted). This looks like a very elegant and general approach. As a sanity check, what does it concretely imply for my question, even in the case $p=2$ or $p=3$ ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One can use power series in the group algebra for other functions (logarithm or even directly square root) - see the book I quoted.